# Why might MediaFoundation's MediaEngine play a video on the 2nd call to play but not the first?

Tags: winapi, directx-11, ms-media-foundation, directx-12

I'm using Microsoft's MediaEnginePlayer DirectX example class [defined here](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/Graphics/VideoTextureUWP) and [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/jj207074(v=vs.105)) in a Win32 desktop application on Windows 10.

After calling [SetSource()](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/blob/master/UWPSamples/Graphics/VideoTextureUWP/MediaEnginePlayer.cpp#L197) on an audio file like this:

```
mePlayer->SetSource(L"c:\\auddio.opus");
```

it automatically begins playing because the class calls Play() after receiving the `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_CANPLAY` event [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/blob/master/UWPSamples/Graphics/VideoTextureUWP/MediaEnginePlayer.cpp#L261).

**But** if given a video:

```
mePlayer->SetSource(L"c:\\video.mp4");  //Won't play
```

it does not playback. To get a video to play I need to explicitly call Play() either before or after the call to SetSource().

```
//This will play
mePlayer->SetSource(L"c:\\video.mp4");
mePlayer->Play();

//And even this will play
mePlayer->Play();
mePlayer->SetSource(L"c:\\video.mp4");
```

But I do not understand why this is. Here is a sample demonstrating the problem: https://www.mediafire.com/file/6b61sxoou94d60r/Test.zip/file

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Tested [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/Graphics/VideoTextureUWP) with different video files and it works for me without calling `mePlayer->Play()` additionally. Make sure you add your video file to the project's Assets folder and set its properties to "Content: Yes" and "Item Type: Media". You will receive `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_LOADEDMETADATA` and then `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_CANPLAY`, after that, video starts playing.

Comment: I can get the sample to work as well. But the class doesn't perform the same for me outside the sample and I do not understand why. The events you mention do fire. The Play() method does get called after `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_CANPLAY` without error. I also get `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_TIMEUPDATE` events. However without me explicitly calling Play() the `GetCurrentTime()` always reports zero.

Comment: Could you show a mini, complete and reproducible sample?

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload one. Maybe I can make a small win32 program I could paste here tomorrow that the class could be dropped into. You don't really need to render the video to test it. If it plays you'll hear the audio.

Comment: Maybe you can share it in Github.

Comment: I don't have an account there. But I'll put a simple solution together you'll be able to run.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Can you please try this solution: https://www.mediafire.com/file/6b61sxoou94d60r/Test.zip/file

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue using your code sample.

Call `MediaEnginePlayer::Play()` on receiving `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_LOADEDMETADATA` solve this issue for me. You can have a try.

About why calling `MediaEnginePlayer::Play()` on receiving `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_CANPLAY` doesn't work I need do a further investigation.

Comment: It also plays for me if Play() is called after `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_LOADEDMETADATA` which is really interesting since I believe it occurs before `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_CANPLAY` and doesn't guarantee enough data has been loaded to be able to successfully begin playback. It's mysterious how the original sample is able to work. Possibly some odd asynchronous issue is occurring? Thank you for looking in to this.

Comment: @cecil If you comment out code lines in `MediaEnginePlayer::TransferFrame()` in UWP sample, same issue reproduced. But if you change `Play()` from  `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_CANPLAY`  to `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_LOADEDMETADATA`, it works. In your Win32 C++ code sample `MediaEnginePlayer::TransferFrame()` never get executed. So we can confirm that this issue is consistent between Win32 C++ and UWP application.

Comment: That's a great observation. I think specifically it's the calling of `IMFMediaEngine::OnVideoStreamTick()` that is making it work and progress with playback. You can comment out everything else in `MediaEnginePlayer::TransferFrame()` and it will play. Perhaps this call is a requirement of video playback. It's still odd to me that a single call to `MediaEnginePlayer::Play()` at a specific time makes it playback anyway though.

Comment: According to the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfmediaengine/ne-mfmediaengine-mf_media_engine_event): `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_CANPLAY` means playback can start, but the Media Engine might need to stop to buffer more data. So from the understanding of the document, it may be unable to play because of buffered data. After testing, I think you can use the `MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_EVENT_LOADEDDATA` flag, the document states: The Media Engine has loaded enough data to render some content (for example, a video frame). And it works fine for me.